# Adding publickey and file into const data in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want to have 'data' construction that includes 'publicKey' and 'file' inside, and want to seperate them in the store as publicKey and file.

How can I make a construction in save.vue as shown below. In other words, I need to send publickey and file both together to the uploadCourseResourceFile function. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
const data = {
  publicKey: this.$route.params.id,
  file: this.file
}
```

save.vue

```
methods: {
  processFiles(event) {
    const chosenFiles = Array.from(event.target.files);
    chosenFiles.map(file => {
      this.$store.dispatch("uploadCourseResourceFile",data).then(response => {});
  });
},
```

store

```
uploadCourseResourceFile(context, data) {
  const coursePublicKey= data.publicKey;
  const file = data.file;
  return courseService.uploadFile(coursePublicKey,file);
},
```

service

```
uploadFile(coursePublicKey,file) {
  return storageService.upload(`/api/courses/${coursePublicKey}/storage /file`, file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `dispatch` with parameters you can simply:

```
this.$store.dispatch("uploadCourseResourceFile", {publicKey: this.$route.params.id, file})
```

And you can access your data from `uploadCourseResourceFile` just like you are doing.

Your `const data` does not make much sense in this case. Accessing `this.file` in this context you are showing will not return what you want.